# WDS not letting me deploy

Tags: wds

You did such a good job answering my last quesiton, I thought i would Throw another one at you guys!

So iv setup Windows deployment service and it worked... Then i tried to capture an image off a PC to test worked well.

Now i want to deploy the image but when i do it keeps going back to the capture screen no matter what option i choose. I know its worked in the past but i cant work out what iv changed for it not to go to that screen.

Any idea's anyone?

Rick

Comment: "it keeps going back to the capture screen" - What does that mean exactly? Can you provide a screenshot? Have you added the captured image to your Image Group?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it sounds like you are still booting to your capture image. You may have to import a new boot image if the other boot images have been converted to capture images. Here are a few guides that may help you with WDS (depending on which version of Windows Server you are using):

•   [Step-by-Step Guide for Windows Deployment Services in Windows Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766320(v=ws.10).aspx)

•   [Windows Deployment Services Getting Started Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771670(v=ws.10).aspx) (Windows Server 2008/2008R2)

•   [Windows Deployment Services Getting Started Guide for Windows Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj648426.aspx)

In addition, I would recommend that you download the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25175) (it’s free). MDT will work with WDS so you can continue deploying over the network, and allows you to be much more flexible with what you can do. MDT and WDS both can manage drivers, but MDT can also manage updates, packages, and install software during the deployment. This allows you to have fewer images, since department specific software can be installed during the deployment, rather than embedded in the image. It also allows you to update software in MDT if a new version is released (i.e. Office, Flash, etc…) rather than loading the image, updating the software and re-capturing.

To help you become more familiar with MDT and to see just how simple deployments can be with this tool, I recommend you check out the following videos:

•   [Deployment Day Session 1: Introduction to MDT 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-deployment-day-session1.aspx)

•   [Deployment Day Session 2: MDT 2012 Advanced](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-deployment-day-session2.aspx)

Here is one walkthrough specific to using MDT with WDS:

•   [Deployment Day Session 3: Deployment using WDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-deployment-day-session3.aspx)

For even more videos, walk-throughs and articles pertaining to the area of deployment, I also suggest the [Deliver and Deploy Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) page from the Springboard Series site on TechNet.

Hope this helps